# Why do my images look pixelated during/after LR/PS post processing?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, facebook

I bought the Nikon D810, Lexar card reader and just started using Creative Cloud (LR then PS).

First, when the picture are loading to the GRID of LR for me to choose the pictures to import, the pictures are blurry. Once I choose 1 image for editing it looks perfectly fine while I'm on LR develop mode. I can zoom in and out to work on the details.

Then, I export the image to PS and it looks fine until I zoom in to start working on the details. The image is completely pixelated when I zoom.

I save the picture (from Raw to Jpeg) onto to desktop. I open the folder and see the picture pixelated once I zoom into it.

When I post it onto Facebook it doesn't look too bad (but not crisp)...

Suggestions and steps into what I need to do. I would Deeply thank you for your instructions. Thanks! sample image attached.. [image]

Comment: How do you export the image to photoshop? At what resolution? We need more information.

Comment: Hi @Hugo and thanks for responding. Well, I always used Elements 11 and just started dabbling with LR & PS. I'm guessing the resolution I used to export it to Photoshop was the default size LR has. Is there a ball park number I should be around prior to exporting? (I would think it's different depending on the style of image of course)...Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Of course images look pixelated when you zoom in, because they are made of pixels. If you don't want to see that, don't zoom in so far.

Comment: I am confused too. Your camera can handle 36 Mpx. And the example you are posting is just a small image. Of course if you zoom it it is pixelated... If that is what you are refering to. It is not crisp... just apply a shapren filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "blurry" pictures you see when LR is loading them to the grid are the smaller JPEG thumbnail/preview versions created by the camera at the time the shot was taken and embedded in the raw file. They are used because the smaller file size of the thumbnails and the fact that the image information in the raw file has already been converted to JPEG allows them to be loaded much faster.

The reason things look so pixelated when you zoom in on a edited image is because the image is (wait for it)... constructed of lots of pixels!

The more pixels an image contains, the more you are magnifying when you zoom in. In the case of the D810, the 7360x4912 resolution of a 36x24mm sensor means each pixel only covers 4.88µ. When you zoom in to 100% (1 camera pixel displayed per 1 screen pixel) you are significantly magnifying the image! If you have a 23" HD (1920x1080 pixels) monitor, looking at one part of the photo at 100% is like looking at a section of a 77x51 inch enlargement of the entire photo! In comparison, looking at an image from an 18MP camera with pixels twice as wide as those of the D810 only magnifies the image to about a 38x25" display size.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info Michael. Very detailed. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here. Easily overcome by going to 'Image size' and changing it back to 300DPI. I found mine changed, strangely, to 72DPI whilst editing.